# Elasticsearch query: range query on two fields, but one is optional field

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to search my index based on a timestamp.

The documents have these field combinations:

- **start_time** and **end_time**

or

- just **start_time** (no **end_time** field)

**Pseudo query:** . 
For a given timestamp, I wish to return all documents where an id matches, and also:
 `timestamp >= start_time && timestamp < end_time`

but if there is no end_time field, then the query needs to be this:
`(not exists end_time) && (timestamp > start_time)`

**Elastic query** . 
This is where I am going mad. I can't get an elastic query equivilent to that pseudo query above. Perhaps I am approaching it the wrong way (entirely possible). Here is what I have:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "id_s": "SomeIdValue"
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "must_not": [
                      {
                        "exists": {
                          "field": "end_time_dt"
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "range": {
                      "start_time_dt": {
                        "lte": "2019-07-12T03:20:22"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "filter": [
                  {
                    "range": {
                      "start_time_dt": {
                        "lte": "2019-07-12T03:20:22"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "range": {
                      "end_time_dt": {
                        "gte": "2019-07-12T03:20:22"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But this gives me `[must] query malformed, no start_object after query name`

How do I construct this query? Am I on the right track?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is syntactically wrong. The correct query would be:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "id_s": "SomeIdValue"
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must_not": [
                    {
                      "exists": {
                        "field": "end_time_dt"
                      }
                    }
                  ],
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "range": {
                        "start_time_dt": {
                          "lte": "2019-07-12T03:20:22"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "range": {
                        "start_time_dt": {
                          "lte": "2019-07-12T03:20:22"
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "range": {
                        "end_time_dt": {
                          "gte": "2019-07-12T03:20:22"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: that has fixed the syntax, thank you - however it returns 0 hits. Is my actual logic correct?

Comment: @Stretch I updated my query with logic correction. You used `lte` and `gte` in opposite way. Also in two case you want only `lt` and `gt`

Comment: actually your first query was correct, and it works - my bad. My lt/gt logic in the original post is also correct - it does not need to be switched. In this query, I am looking for documents that existed at the time `2019-07-12T03:20:22`. Therefore, the start time must be `lt` this time, and the end time must be `gt` this time. If you switch it back, I'll mark as the correct answer. Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: @Stretch Reverted back the query

Answer (score 0):

There is a slight mistake in the logic. Ideally, comparison should be like this `gte` start_time_dt and `lte`  end_time_dt. You did other way round so that translates to   timestamp <= start_time && timestamp > end_time.

The correct query is

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "id_s": "SomeIdValue"
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must_not": [
                    {
                      "exists": {
                        "field": "end_time_dt"
                      }
                    }
                  ],
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "range": {
                        "start_time_dt": {
                          "gte": "2019-07-12T03:20:22"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "range": {
                        "start_time_dt": {
                          "gte": "2019-07-12T03:20:22"
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "range": {
                        "end_time_dt": {
                          "lte": "2019-07-12T03:20:22"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: I think I was correct actually. I want to see if a given timestamp falls within start and end, so `start<-----TS------>end` - so, `ts gte start && ts lte end`

Comment: Yes, but in the query you have ` {
                    "range": {
                      "start_time_dt": {
                        "lte": "2019-07-12T03:20:22"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "range": {
                      "end_time_dt": {
                        "gte": "2019-07-12T03:20:22"
                      }
                    }
                  }`

Comment: which is correct. I need the start time to be earlier than the timestamp (`"2019-07-12T03:20:22`) and the end time must come after `2019-07-12T03:20:22`, hence gte (or maybe just gt will do)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this block should be `must` not `should` as mentioned in the answer. The reason I say is both those conditions: must ( not exists AND range ) is what the OP intention I believe

```
{
          "bool": {
            "must": [     <====== mentioned it as should
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must_not": [
                    {
                      "exists": {
                        "field": "end_time_dt"
                      }
                    }
                  ],
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "range": {
                        "start_time_dt": {
                          "lte": "2019-07-12T03:20:22"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
```